# iOS INApp Purchase Auto renewal subscription?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I have implemented auto renewable subscription (Monthly and Yearly Renewal).I have purchased successfully and verified the receipt. But I don't know how to verify the recipet  when subscription auto renewed.(Successfully OR failed). SO please help

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. First, your app get notified, when subscription is renewed, actually new purchased transaction received, and you should resend receipt to your server or locally on device set proper configuration. Second, in apple response of receipt validation there is a field "latest_receipt_info", you can retry receipt validation on server in the end of period of subscription and get actual info about your subscription (for instance, if client can't send receipt for some reasons). Combined approach is the best way.